# Identify children's story about magic book, eggshells, and invisible children

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a children's story and am stumped. In one chapter of the book the children, two girls and a boy I believe, make a recipe or pottage resulting in magic eggshells (in my memory the shells were blue). The children would become invisible if they had the eggshells on their person. The setting was modern, although the story sounds like a possible rendition of changeling folk lore, but I don't remember any "evil" characters.

Answer (score 4):

[M for Mischief](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0696713950) by Richard Parker :)

[Summary from GoodReads (also has cover image)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2253481.M_for_Mischief):

> Three Marlowe children find a stove in the summer house with two
>   settings O for ordinary and M for mischef. What mischief the children
>   get into with a magic cookbook.

Comment: Please add a synopsis for this story so that it's clearer why this might be the answer.

Comment: I remember this story - they boiled eggs then found that the eggshells (which were now blue) turned them invisible when the children were touching them. The boy stuck his to his shoulder so he wouldn't lose it, but it came off in the bath. I believe there were other "spells" they could do with the stove but the effects wore off overnight (as all good spells do!).